# How to load a .so file statically with make?

Tags: makefile

Is there a  makefile modification which can help me load a shared library(*.so file) statically?

Comment: The part of your makefile calling the linker (ld?) would be helpful

Comment: Im on linux.The application() is not able to load shared library at runtime.So I want to load the.so files  statically.

Answer (score 2):

You can't link a shared library statically (or share a static one); they're different animals. What you can do is build a static library from the object files, or if that's not possible you can convert a shared library into a static one with a tool like [Statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/), then link that.

A makefile is a kind of scripting tool; it automates tasks you could do by hand. You must figure out how to do something by hand before you ask Make to do it.